# Music genre similar to brain.fm synthesised music

Tags: identify-this-song, similar-artists

Recently i've came across this service brain.fm

This music does help to focus indeed, but after couple of months of usage it feels too familiar (i don't know the specific word in english to describe this feeling, but i hope you get what i mean).

So, what musicians/genres should i look for to listen to similar music?

Jon Hopkins, Nils Frahm are somewhere close, but not what i'm looking for. Their music is awesome, but it is not quite suitable for deep sessions of coding.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve used Brain.fm for a couple of sessions only. For what I’ve listen on the *Focus* section I can suggest to search into the so-called [Dub Techno world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dub_techno).

You can find something to start with in those articles from Fact mag’s *[“The 25 best dub techno tracks of all time”](http://www.factmag.com/2014/05/21/the-25-best-dub-techno-tracks-of-all-time/)* and Thump Vice’s *[“A Bulls#itter's Guide to Dub Techno”](https://thump.vice.com/en_ca/article/a-bullshitters-guide-to-dub-techno)*. Or, if you want some recent names, I would say Andy Stott’s *[Luxury Problems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-aGEmhzQFr8)* (and his previous works) and some tunes from [Vladislav Delay](https://www.discogs.com/artist/406-Vladislav-Delay).

A localist suggestion: [Voices From the Lake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZLYl-1q6Q4) and some [Donato Dozzy](https://www.discogs.com/artist/202097-Donato-Dozzy) tunes, both solo and collaborations, work always very well with me.

And if you don't find any of these good for what you need, you can always give a try to some of [alternatives to brain.fm](http://alternativeto.net/software/brain-fm/) you can find around the web.